# Django - Whatsapp Sessions for scheduled messages

Tags: django, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp

I'm developing a system where users, in addition to all the bureaucratic part, can register their clients' whatsapp so that automatic billing messages, congratulations, etc. are sent. Where the user would read the QR code and the system would be in charge of sending messages over time, using the user's whatsapp, thus opening a user<-> clinet conversation.  I'm dividing this problem into parts, for now I'm trying to read the Whatsapp Web Qr Code and display it in a template. This is already happening. The problem is that the webdriver is terminated first, as soon as the image is returned to the template, then the session cannot be validated. The webdriver remains open forever, or closes before the image is sent to the template, the image needs to go to the template via return (or another way) and the webdriver remains active for a while. How to solve this concurrent task?

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import base64
import time
from django.shortcuts import render

def read_qr_code(request):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    # driver.implicitly_wait(30) # mantém o webdriver ativo por 2 minutos
    driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    qr_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/canvas')))


    qr_image_binary = qr_element.screenshot_as_png
    qr_image_base64 = base64.b64encode(qr_image_binary).decode('utf-8')

    context = {
        'image_data': qr_image_base64
    }

    # send_qr(request, context)
    
    # time.sleep(20)  # aguarda por 2 minutos
    # driver.quit()  # fecha o webdriver

    return render(request, 'read_qr_code.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problmes using Threds, the code is.

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import base64
import time
from django.shortcuts import render
import threading

def quit_driver_thread():
    time.sleep(40)
    driver.quit()

def read_qr_code(request):
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.implicitly_wait(120)
    driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    qr_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/canvas')))
    qr_image_binary = qr_element.screenshot_as_png
    qr_image_base64 = base64.b64encode(qr_image_binary).decode('utf-8')
    context = {
        'image_data': qr_image_base64
    }
    thread = threading.Thread(target=quit_driver_thread)
    thread.start()
    return render(request, 'read_qr_code.html', context)
```